# Territories on lease world wide

Tags: territory

What are the territories given on lease (or any other way) by some country to other country currently?
Is there such map?

Comment: Do you mean like "Guantanamo Bay", or "Hong Kong  in the 20th century"?

Comment: Did you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concessions_and_leases_in_international_relations

Comment: @JamesK yes, like that. I heard, Hambantota (Srilanka) is on lease to China.

Comment: Sri Lanka remains the government authority in Hambantota, even if the Chinese Government has leased some land, so I don't think this is an example.

Comment: "by some country to other country". The list would vary a bit depending on the purpose and terms, e.g. if state-owned companies are to be included and what kind of jurisdiction is asserted for the leased area.

Comment: Baikonur Cosmodrome in Kazachstan maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be only two, if you ignore purely ceremonial leases such as the "JFK Memorial in Runnymead".

Khmeimim Air Base in Syria is leased to the Russian government for a period of 49 years from 2015 to 2064

Guantanamo Bay Base is leased "in perpetuity" by the USA from Cuba.

Both are military facilities with no civilian government.

Comment: The question has a loose definition of lease ("given on lease (or any other way)"), not a strict definition.

Comment: Djibouti allows multiple powers (some of whom are rivals of each other) to lease bases on its territory.

Comment: There was already a [Tartus lease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_naval_facility_in_Tartus) (also for 49 years) approved by the Syrian parliament when you posted this answer. "The logistic facility shall enjoy full immunity from the civil and administrative jurisdiction of Syria." https://tass.com/defense/926348 That's distinct from the airbase. Also I suspect the list is woefully incomplete. The US had a 10-year least on their Djibouti base signed in 2014 https://www.voanews.com/a/us-expands-presence-in-strategically-located-djibouti/1907900.html It was probalby extended.

Comment: Aside from the military-logistic zone, Russian companies also secured a long-term deal (also 49 years) for the management of civilian port zone in Tartus, a bit later
https://www.france24.com/en/20190612-syria-parliament-okays-russian-lease-tartus-port-state-media "the six directors would be split equally between Damascus and Stroytransgaz, but the board's leadership would reserved for the Russian company". Which is probably how most Chinese leases work. So there's the additional grey area of state-owned companies getting long leases.

Comment: The [French](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/defence/djibouti-lures-foreign-powers-with-strategic-position/articleshow/80850508.cms?from=mdr) and the [Chinese](https://theworld.org/stories/2016-05-03/china-building-its-first-overseas-military-base-djibouti-right-next-key-us-one) bases in Djibouti also seem to come with 10-year leases.

Comment: Even Japan [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Self-Defense_Force_Base_Djibouti) a base in Djibouti. I wasn't able to find any details on the terms other that it being described as a "lease". IDK what kind of jurisdiction arrangements any of the Djibouti bases have...

Comment: Judging by the pre-2009 US SOFA https://2001-2009.state.gov/documents/organization/97620.pdf it seems that these Djibouti bases are still governed by Djibouti law [even during the lease], so [officially] not quite in the same bin as the Cuba & Syria ones, but the Q wasn't exactly clear on that angle.

Comment: I suspect however that local law is lot less strictly enforced on the Djibouti bases than it is e.g. [at Ramstein](https://www.ramstein.af.mil/About/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/303721/status-of-forces-agreement/) so there's that practical angle.

Comment: What about the UK military bases in Cyprus and the US military base in Diego Garcia?